# firefox with pdf.js - reload a pdf inside an iframe

Tags: firefox, iframe, reload, pdf.js

I have a pdf inside an iframe and a description text beside it. 
In the text, I have links which should scroll the pdf to the desired page.

```
$('a.pdf-page').click(function(){
  var iframe = document.getElementById('#pdf-iframe');

  var page_no = $(this).attr( 'data-page' );

  iframe.contentWindow.location.hash = '#navpanes=0&toolbar=0&page=' + page_no;
  iframe.contentWindow.location.reload( true );
});
```

This works great in chrome, but firefox (v 23) gives me this error: "Permission denied to access property 'hash'".

Does anybody know why?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Trying to access almost anything off of the window object containing the PDF results in a permission denied. When I say "containing," in this context I mean that the source of the iframe points to an endpoint which streams PDF data back. This was not an issue previously using the Acrobat plugin.